# Strange error when trying to install PIP

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, pip

Trying install PIP.
I have python 2.7 installed on Windows 7 (32-bit)

I created a file called *get-pip.py* as instructed here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
When I run that file with python, I get the following error. The user account has admin rights.

Does anyone know what is going on?

```
C:\Python27>python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "c:\users\sek~1.sek\appdata\local\temp\tmpvkex0l\pip.zip\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sek~1.sek\appdata\local\temp\tmpvkex0l\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sek~1.sek\appdata\local\temp\tmpvkex0l\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sek~1.sek\appdata\local\temp\tmpvkex0l\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sek~1.sek\appdata\local\temp\tmpvkex0l\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sek~1.sek\appdata\local\temp\tmpvkex0l\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\request.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sek~1.sek\appdata\local\temp\tmpvkex0l\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\filepost.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sek~1.sek\appdata\local\temp\tmpvkex0l\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\fields.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\utils.py", line 313
    fallback charset='us-ascii'):
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Python27>
```

Comment: Have you installed a library "email" ?  If yes, try to remove it then install PIP. It looks like something include the library to use email but to get pip installed you wont need it

Comment: @max246 I just installed python, and nothing else.

Comment: I would adjust the error into the utils.py but only looking if something is missing, maybe it is missing an underscore in that variable. Never had this issue, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Do I need to install pip?](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)**
>
> `pip` is already installed if you're using **Python 2 >=2.7.9** or **Python 3 >=3.4** binaries downloaded from python.org, but you'll need to upgrade pip.

Just add `pip` to your environment path:

```
<python install dir>/Scripts/
```

Which can be easily done using an elevated command-prompt:

```
setx path "%path%;<python install dir>/Scripts/"
```

---

**Then, upgrade it:**

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```